# Gallery android:unselectedAlpha

Tags: android, gallery, alpha-transparency

I have a Gallery that works perfectly, except only the first element is ever displayed at full alpha.

I have the Gallery's style set to style="android:galleryItemBackground", and android:unselectedAlpha="0.75" is also set. This works, in that the first element is shown without transparency, and the second appears to be faded some.

The issue is, when I scroll the gallery, the items never become unfaded. They're all alpha=0.75, even when they're the selected item. The items do have an OnItemClickListener set, and this listener works fine.

I am unable to find an answer to how to get this working, so I thought I'd ask here.

[ edit ]
I've also tried setting an OnItemSelectedListener and manually setting the View's alpha to 1 if the position = selectedPosition in the getView of the Adapter. No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add background on every of its child view

This is one example code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    // have to set background to make selection alpha works
    view.setBackgroundColor(0x22ffffff);


    return view;
}
```

Hope it helps